# diff script error

Tags: bash, shell, diff

when i execute below command it works properly 
(it provide difference between to text files)

```
diff <(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/msmscgateway |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}') <(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/last/msmscgatewaylast |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}')
```

when i run it thru script it gives below error

```
test4.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `(' t
```

Help me to fix the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sh test.sh
```

This should be

```
bash test.sh
```

[`ref`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)